# Why is this QString to const char* conversion producing a Debian identifier on Windows?

Tags: windows, string, qt, qstring

I'm trying to wrap libssh2 in Qt, and have the following code:

```
const char* username = inUsername.toLocal8Bit().data();
const char* password = inPass.toLocal8Bit().data();
```

Problem is, that username and password doesn't connect to the system.  Why?

Because, according to the debugger,

```
username  "5.1p1 Debian-6ubuntu2"
password  "5.1p1 Debian-6ubuntu2"
```

Those are not the values I've given for the username or password.  I've tried toAscii, toLatin1, and appending (or not) the .data().  Still, I get these values, instead of the expected values.  I'm on Windows, which is why it's even more troubling, since, as far as I can tell, nothing I have was compiled on Debian or Ubuntu.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code:

```
const char* username = inUsername.toLocal8Bit().data();
```

is equivalent to this:

```
const char * username;
{
    const QByteArray l8b = inUsername.toLocal8Bit();
    username = l8b.data();
}
```

Do you see what's going on? By the time the statement has executed, the temporary `QByteArray` has been deleted by the compiler again. Since `data()` only returns a pointer to the internal `QByteArray` buffer, `username` now points to deleted/freed memory.

To solve the problem, make `username` and `password` `QByteArray`s instead of `const char*`s, and use `username.data()`, `password.data()` instead where you used `username`, `password` before.

Comment: Wow.  Just wow.  I got that code off of the Qt help page (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#toLocal8Bit), but of course, they don't mention that little bit of trivia.  I don't know whether or not to be incredibly angry with them or just shake my head in frustration, as this little thing has only cost me a couple of days.  Thanks for the help, it's made my life world's easier.

Comment: @mmr: I've noticed some gaps in the documentation, but I don't think this is one of them.  The page you linked specifically says it returns a QByteArray, and the documentation for data() on the QByteArray (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qbytearray.html#data) says that it returns a pointer that is only valid until the byte array is changed or destroyed.